comfirm en php que dirija a una url
¿Cómo hago para que al hacer esta comprobación mediante el if salga este confirm (echo 1)  y que al darle en Aceptar vaya a una web específica (echo 2); pero al contrario, le den cancelar, se cierre el confirm y permanezca en la web que lo contiene (como suele suceder con los confirm)?
$message2="Ya hay una nota agregada, desea almacenar otra?";

    if($hays >=1){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('$message2');</script>";       
            echo '<a href="notas.php?dato1='.$dato1" target="_parent">
        <button class="boton" name="button2" id="button2">Notas</button>
    </a>';  
    }

Pensé que haciendo así:
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function confirmation1(){
        if(confirm("Aun no ha realizado la inspección, desea realizarla?")){
       return true;
      window.location.href = "notas.php?dato='.$dato.'";
        } else {
       return false;
    }
     }
</script>

y que para que al cargar el php dispare la función...
if($hays >=1){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>confirmation1();</script>";        
}else{

en principio me funciona de esta manera pero no quiero que sea mediante enlace...
<a href="elimina_contrato.php?dato=$idcon onclick='return confirmation()'>Nota</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
     function confirmation(){
        if(confirm("¿Desea agregar Notas?")){
       return true;
        } else {
       return false;
    }
     }
</script>


Usa Sweet Alert para ese propósito, yo creo que es la mejor opción

tienes razon, voy a estudiarlas un poco, pero por lo pronrto necesito asi en js purito.. saludos

Tienes que controlar el submit del botón, mediante el uso de JS, y utilizar el prevent default, para evitar que se emita el formulario antes de lo que quieras hacer. Es el mismo principio que OCHOA te da con sweet alert (solo que este, ya está bonito y bien hecho). Busca "como hacer un submit con js y prevent default. Intenta algo, y luego actualiza que has logrado.

recuerda que puedes directamente editar la publicación, y agregar/quitar lo que necesites. Nosotros nos enteramos de las ediciones de todos modos.

oki gracias por tu ayuda ya lo puse en el mensaje.. (edité)

Ok, hasta donde veo vas bien. Pero quieres que la página al cargar dispare la función? o que el botón sea el que la dispare? y el return true, esta demás en la confirmación si quieres hacer la redirección.

bueno te cuento... esta pagina al cargar hace una comprobación a la base de datos y si la comprobación es afirmativa es donde sale el confirm, pero  lo que deseo es que para facilitar el paso me gustaría que al cerrar el confirm (dando en el botón Aceptar) le cargue la web a donde tiene que ir el usuario. para que le sea practica al usuario.

Ok, con los cambios realizados, funciona? y te pido actualizar toda la pregunta, ahora que sabemos de mejor manera que quieres lograr.

pues funciona si disparo mediante un enlace.. (edite el mensaje)

En el segundo código de tu pregunta el error está en que colocas  return true; ANTES del  window.location.href por lo que tu función nunca llega a ejecutar el cambio de página. Quita esos return de tu función.

Si quieres solamente ejecutar el confirm durante la carga, puedes hacerlo utilizando el DOM.
Recuerda de todos modos, verificar correctamente el valor de $dato. Y realizar un control en caso de errores de este mismo.
Según los ejemplos, no se como quieres pasarle la variable, si con PHP, o de otro modo, por ahora lo dejo simple.
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        if (confirm("¿Desea agregar Notas?")) {
            window.location.href = "elimina_contrato.php?dato=" + dato;
        }
    });
</script>


Hola he abierto una nueva consulta al respecto, pues tengo un inconveniente la prrimera vez me carga la URL que se cumple, pero al hacer la comprobacion pareciera que la otra condicion else no, no se por que no me carga la 0otra URL
